# Kohana 3: using maintainable routes

Tags: php, kohana

I'm using Kohana v3 for a web project, and today I found myself writing this:

```
echo Html::anchor('user/view/'.$user->id, "See user's profile");
```

If I rename the `action_view` method in the User controller, the link will be broken. To avoid this, I created a function in the User model that returns the URL used for viewing the user's profile:

```
echo Html::anchor($user->url_view(), "See user's profile");
```

There is another (cleaner) way to do this (similar to Django's `url()` and `{% url %}`)?

PS: Excuse my English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you want reverse routing using the route name. Try something like this:

```
echo Html::anchor(
   Route::get('your_route_name')->uri(array('id'=>$user->id)), 
   "See user's profile"
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about the Route class.

Answer (score 0):

what do you need is called reverse routing. you have a route "name" (with parameters eventually) and you associate it with a module/action pair or with a whatever/path.

then you use this route name instead of the direct controller/action path so you can change the name of the actions as you like in future.

<strike>[here's a page that describes this](http://www.ninjapenguin.co.uk/blog/2008/10/18/kohana-23-routing/). be aware that in kohana 2.x reverse routing is not supported (so when he refers to 2.3 he really means 3.x)</strike>

Comment: You're correct about reverse routing, but that linked example is outdated. The best resources are the official userguide: http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/ and the unofficial wiki: http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php